# Commenting: Constructive vs Hypercritical

Tags: discussion, comments

I just wanted to ask whilst there exists a [code of conduct](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/conduct) which points to the requirement to approach people with politeness and the like, I do feel that sometimes there are certain users who in their praiseworthy mission for the truth, may sometimes be overly critical. I appreciate that there is a [milchemta shel torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.42a.6?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and that sometimes we can get worked up as we strive to battle out a true p'shat, but I just wonder if it can be done in a more patient and polite manner.

On many occasions I find that people may give weaker answers and immediately the comments blow up and go crazy. Sometimes it is only because they have either not understood something right or they lack the relevant background knowledge. By the same token, I appreciate that there are some users who post answers more for political purposes or to advance their own baseless viewpoints. So whilst it is right to correct a point that is not valid or untrue, I do feel that we have lost a modicum of basic respect.

We are currently in the aseres yemei teshuva, and thus undergoing a sense of introspection - would it not be fair to mention the dictum from Chazal - 'derech eretz kadmah l'Torah' - to treat each other with respect which precedes Torah? And if so, should there not be a revision of the code of conduct to negate the sometimes quite negative and harsh tone employed in the comments section?

Comment: I believe that the existing Code of Conduct encompasses the type of behavior you're recommending. I support the re-emphasis of these issues that this post calls for.

Comment: I apologize if I upset you in any way with my comments. I didn't mean them or write them with any negative intent or harshness. It's often hard to pick up on someone's tone in a written format. I can try to be more cautious in the future with how I write, to avoid giving false impressions.

Comment: Thanks @Robev - pls note this post was not a reaction to our interaction I have been meaning to write it for a while. I can handle it, I just feel very upset for people who have may have little or no connection to yiddushkeit who ask a question out of genuine curiosity and are now finally engaging with their heritage only for them to get knocked back and presented with a negative response.

Comment: possibly related https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3433/759

Comment: Thanks @DoubleAA but it is not related. My point is purely for people to be conscious of their tone when writing comments

Comment: Is it possible to bounty a question on Meta? :-)