# PTIJ - Mah Nishtanah Mi Yodeya

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

How is this site different from all other sites?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: See also: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On most other sites, the best content may rise or lie flat; on this site, the best content only rises.

On most other sites, you can ask about all kinds of topics; on this site, only Judaism (the local definition of which is [sometimes bitterly debated](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope)).

On most other sites, you can categorize posts at most once; on this site, you can put up to five tags.

On most other sites, users must lie back and leave editing and moderation to professionals; on this site, users may lie back or sit up and help run the place.

On most other sites, content is cooked up in just one kind of post; on this site, it may be questions, answers, or comments.

If you haven't yet, read this information again [in its traditional form](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour), and you'll get a prize at the end! Hopefully, that'll keep you awake, and prompt you to [*something something*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I honestly can't see anyone topping this answer!

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Maybe by doing something similar in Hebrew?

Comment: On some other sites you can edit a post at most once; here it is considered meritorious to edit a post twice.

Answer (score 2):

מה נשתנה האתר הזה מכל האתרות?

שבכל האתרות השאלות הטובות עולות ויורדות, האתר הזה כלם עולות.

שבכל האתרות אנו שואלים כל השאלות, האתר הזה בלם ביהדות, שפירושו לפעמים [נתווכחו במרירות](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope).

שבכל האתרות אנו מסווגים רק פעם אחת, האתר הזה עד חמשה פעמים.

שבכל האתרות אנו מסובין ונותנים ל[מוד](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)ים כל העריכה, האתר הזה כולנו מסובין או יושבים ועורכים.

שבכל האתרות כל התוכן הוי בסוג אחד, האתר הזה יש שאלות תירוצים והערות.

This is a Hebrew (rough) translation of [Isaac Moses’s answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4512/9682), based on [his comment there](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/ptij-mah-nishtanah-mi-yodeya/4512#comment14171_4512).

Comment: Well translated!